# Purposely having a query return blank entries at regular intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting

I want to write a query that returns 3 results followed by blank results followed by the next 3 results, and so on. So if my database had this data:

```
CREATE TABLE table (a integer, b integer, c integer, d integer);

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c,d) 
VALUES (1,2,3,4),
       (5,6,7,8),
       (9,10,11,12),
       (13,14,15,16),
       (17,18,19,20),
       (21,22,23,24),
       (25,26,37,28);
```

I would want my query to return this

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
 ,  ,  , 
13,14,15,16
17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24
  ,  ,  ,
25,26,27,28
```

I need this to work for arbitrarily many entries that I select for, have three be grouped together like this.

I'm running postgresql 8.3

Comment: Your display code should be in charge of the formatting.  Your database code should never know about how it's being displayed.  This is especially relevant when putting it into a document where things can change...
So, can you change the PDF program?

Comment: No, I cannot. The only way I can affect what is displayed is by editing the query that is passed in to the program.

Comment: What determines the 3 row limit?  Is there some aspect of the data that signifies it as a 'delimiter'?

Comment: @Nathen exactly. Every three entries (when sorted a particular way) can be grouped together. And I'm being asked to delimit everything in these meaningful groups of three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work **flawlessly in PostgreSQL 8.3**

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM  (
    SELECT rn, 0 AS rk, (x[rn]).*
    FROM  (
        SELECT x, generate_series(1, array_upper(x, 1)) AS rn
        FROM  (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT tbl FROM tbl) AS x) x
    ) y

    UNION  ALL
    SELECT generate_series(3, (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl), 3), 1, (NULL::tbl).*
    ORDER  BY rn, rk
) z
```

#### Major points

- Works for a query that selects all columns of `tbl`.
- Works for **any** table.
- For selecting arbitrary columns you have to substitute `(NULL::tbl).*` with a matching number of NULL columns in the second query.
- Assuming that `NULL` values are ok for "blank" rows.
- If not, you'll have to cast your columns to `text` in the first and substitute `''` for `NULL` in the second SELECT.
- Query will be slow with very big tables.

If I had to do it, I would write a **plpgsql function** that loops through the results and inserts the blank rows. But you mentioned you had no direct access to the db ...

Comment: +1 Thanks - Never having used PostgreSQL, I was not aware of the `array` function, or the combination use.

Comment: @X-Zero: this is actually pretty advanced stuff. Most users wouldn't be aware of all of it. Especially the multiple use of the complex type that is present for every table.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, there's not an easy way to do this, and generally, you shouldn't try.  The database is concerned with what your data actually is, not how it's going to be displayed.  It's not an appropriate scope of responsibility to expect your database to return "dummy" or "extra" data so that some down-stream process produces a desired output.  The generating script needs to do that.

As you can't change your down-stream process, you *could* (read that with a significant degree of skepticism and disdain) add things like this:

```
Select Top 3
  a, b, c, d
From 
  table
Union Select Top 1
  '', '', '', ''
From 
  table
Union Select Top 3 Skip 3
  a, b, c, d
From
  table
```

Please, don't actually try do that.

Comment: I agree that it would make alot more sense that way, but I can't in any way edit the generating pdf program. The only thing I can edit is the query I pass in to the program.

Comment: @Snitse - I added a union approach that might work for you.  The `skip` may not be right for your database, but it should have some syntax for skipping rows or starting mid-way through a result set.  This is ... ugly, tbh, and I don't advise using it.  If the formatting is a necessary requirement then whomever is in charge of the PDF Generation needs to accommodate it.

Comment: I sympathize with your unease at writing a query like this, but I cant help it. Also, I need to be able to select an arbitrary number of elements and have a space between every three. Unless I'm missing something, this wouldn't work for arbitrarily many elements.

Comment: @Snitse - You're right.  In order to achieve arbitrary rows you'll have to look into looping (if your RDBMS supports it) or retrieve a total row count ahead of time, then use some other scripting language to manually patch in the necessary union statements.  It's ... not pleasant.

Comment: Tunrs out, there is a simple way after all. The difficulty was due to the old version involved. PostgreSQL is concerned with much more than just "what the data is". Your claim is from the perspective of a python programmer and not the absolute truth you make it out to be. In many use cases (well, not in this particular weird one) it is preferable to process data right at the source, in the database. That's what postgres has all the procedural languages for, even pl/python. And of course, that's coming from the perspective of a postgresql-centered programmer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it (at least on DB2 - there doesn't appear to be equivalent functionality for your version of PostgreSQL).
No looping needed, although there is a bit of trickery involved...
Please note that though this *works*, it's *really* best to change your display code.

Statement requires CTEs (although that can be re-written to use other table references), and OLAP functions (I *guess* you could re-write it to `count()` previous rows in a subquery, but...).

```
WITH dataList (rowNum, dataColumn) as (SELECT CAST(CAST(:interval as REAL) / 
            (:interval - 1) * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dataColumn) as INTEGER), 
                                              dataColumn
                                       FROM dataTable), 
     blankIncluder(rowNum, dataColumn) as (SELECT rowNum, dataColumn
                                           FROM dataList
                                           UNION ALL
                                           SELECT rowNum - 1, :blankDataColumn
                                           FROM dataList
                                           WHERE MOD(rowNum - 1, :interval) = 0
                                           AND rowNum > :interval)
SELECT *
FROM dataList
ORDER BY rowNum
```

This will generate a list of those elements from the datatable, with a 'blank' line every `interval` lines, as ordered by the initial query.  The result set only has 'blank' lines between existing lines - there are no 'blank' lines on the ends.

Comment: @ypercube - Yeah, which is why I posted a _general_, 'will work in most versions' form.  There's still ways to get around this (some really terrible), especially if you can pass in multiple statements for execution - create view on the fly, or a temp table, then `count()` previous rows to get `row_number` (which is the trickiest part!).